# laply is part of what package in R?

Tags: r, lapply

`laply` for R is part of what package?

I get:

```
 "Error: could not find function "laply"".
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you're simply missing one of the p's?

Comment: It would be useful to clarify whether you really mean `lapply` (i.e. this is a typo), or whether you are looking for `laply` ...

Comment: See documentation for `apropos` (`?apropos`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: could not find function ... in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r)

Comment: To the editor (@user1317221_G): since the OP never told us, it's not entirely clear whether they meant to look for `lapply` and misspelled it in the body of the question, or whether they meant to look for `laply` and misspelled it in the title ... although I would guess that the latter (as your edit takes for granted) is slightly more likely

Comment: @ Ben Bolker, cheers. understood, i'll take care.

Answer (score 17):

A useful way to find functions that are *somewhere* in some contributed package on CRAN is

```
install.packages("sos")
library("sos")
findFn("laply")
```

(of course, the first command is only necessary once per R installation ...)

In this case, you get

```
> findFn("laply")
found 5 matches
```

and a web page opens in your web browser that shows you (as stated above) that there is an `laply` function in the `plyr` package.

Of course, `findFn()` is much more broadly useful -- for example, you could try `findFn("compositional data analysis")` (if that was what you were interested in).

Comment: I did `RSiteSearch("laply")` and the first hit was this: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/plyr/html/laply.html

Answer (score 10):

`laply` is a function in Hadley's "plyr" package. The convention is that the first letter refers to the input class and the second letter refers to the output class so `laply` takes a list and returns an array.

```
install.packages("plyr")
require(plyr)
?laply
```

Edit: Now that the question has changed the answer is now the base package. (But if the error message was as posted it did imply a misspelling.)

Comment: I hate it when people call me Wickham :( It makes me feel like a badly behaved child in an English grammar school.

Comment: Sorry, Hadley. I thought I was being respectful. Unless of course you want to be Prof. Wickham?

Comment: @hadley: Someone upvoted this and it made me realize I had failed to honor your your request. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

Try typing:

```
?lapply
```

And you'll see at the top of the documentation:

```
package:base
```

The message "Could not find function laply" is not surprising if, as here, you mis-spelled it with one "p", instead of two.

**EDIT:** as others pointed out, the plyr package provides *laply*; you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing the package plyr. install:

```
install.packages("plyr")
```

Comment: how does this add anything to the existing answers?