# error with function regmatches using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the function regmatches, in R, but i'm getting an error (R says it can't find the function).

I'm quite tired now and maybe I'm doing some really silly mistake. However, I don't know what's wrong.

I tried to use ??regmatches, but it didn't find anything.

Next I tried the "sos" package and function findFn("regmatches"), but it returned:

found 0 matches
x has zero rows;  nothing to display.
Mensagens de aviso perdidas:
In findFn("regmatches") : HIT not found in HTML;  processing one page only.

I don't know what else to do.

I know I may be doing a silly mistake like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004710/lapply-is-part-of-what-package-in-r), but I don't know what else to do. Below is my session info:

R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004710/lapply-is-part-of-what-package-in-r) LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252

attached base packages:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004710/lapply-is-part-of-what-package-in-r) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004710/lapply-is-part-of-what-package-in-r) sos_1.3-1  brew_1.0-6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004710/lapply-is-part-of-what-package-in-r) tools_2.12.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`regmatches` was added in R 2.14.0...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry guys. It happens that is was a silly mistake. After almost giving up, I decided to check if it was a problem with my version of R. So, I took a look at the CRAN webpage and found this under what's new with R 2.14.

New function regmatches() for extracting or replacing matched or non-matched substrings from match data obtained by regexpr(), gregexpr() and regexec().

So, It's time to update R. I thought that using version 2.12.2 wasn't that bad, but it happens it was.